# Delete records from multiple tables when deleting a subproject

Tags: c#, performance, linq

In my program I am deleting subprojects using LINQ. It's incredibly slow. There is a lot of cascade on delete's here so I am deleting from multiple tables. Any help and tips would be appreciated.

Here is an overview of the code

When you delete a subProject you must delete

- Activities

  which you must delete

  - ActivityDocuments
  - ActivityNotes
  - ActivityPersons

    - ActivityPersonRoles
  - ActivityMachines
  - PredActivityLinks
  - SuccActivityLinks
  - CommunicationThreads

    - threadContentTag
    - threadParticipants
    - threadMessages

And each subproject can have nested subprojects with the same structure. I am looking for a faster way to do this than the code below. I plan on replacing all of those `.Remove()` calls with `.Clear()`

```
public void DeleteSubProject(SubProject subProject)
{
    foreach (Activity activity in subProject.Activities.ToList())
    {
        UnitOfWork.ActivityService.DeleteActivity(activity);
    }

    subProject.Activities.Clear();

    foreach (SubProjectDocument subProjectDocument in subProject.SubProjectDocuments.ToList())
    {
        subProject.SubProjectDocuments.Remove(subProjectDocument);
        UnitOfWork.SubProjectDocumentService.Delete(subProjectDocument);
    }

    foreach (SubProjectNote subProjectNote in subProject.SubProjectNotes.ToList())
    {
        subProject.SubProjectNotes.Remove(subProjectNote);
        UnitOfWork.SubProjectNoteService.Delete(subProjectNote);
    }

    foreach (SubProjectPerson subProjectPerson in subProject.SubProjectPersons.ToList())
    {
        subProject.SubProjectPersons.Remove(subProjectPerson);
        UnitOfWork.SubProjectPersonService.Delete(subProjectPerson);
    }

    foreach (SubProject childSubProject in subProject.ChildSubProjects.ToList())
    {
        subProject.ChildSubProjects.Remove(childSubProject);
        DeleteSubProject(childSubProject);
    }

    Delete(subProject);
}
```

Here is deleting an activity

```
public void DeleteActivity(Activity activity)
{
    //delete documents
    foreach (ActivityDocument ad in activity.ActivityDocuments.ToList())
    {
        activity.ActivityDocuments.Remove(ad);
        UnitOfWork.ActivityDocumentService.Delete(ad);
    }

    //delete notes
    foreach (ActivityNote an in activity.ActivityNotes.ToList())
    {
        activity.ActivityNotes.Remove(an);
        UnitOfWork.ActivityNoteService.Delete(an);
    }

    //delete people
    foreach (ActivityPerson ap in activity.ActivityPersons.ToList())
    {
       //    // the following call cascades the delete
        UnitOfWork.ActivityPersonService.DeleteActivityPerson(ap);
    }

    activity.ActivityPersons.Clear();

    foreach (CommunicationThread thread in activity.CommunicationThreads.ToList())
    {
        activity.CommunicationThreads.Remove(thread);
        UnitOfWork.CommunicationThreadService.DeleteThread(thread);
    }

    //delete machines
    foreach (ActivityMachine am in activity.ActivityMachines.ToList())
    {
        activity.ActivityMachines.Remove(am);
        UnitOfWork.ActivityMachineService.Delete(am);
    }

    //remove pred links
    foreach (ActivityLink al in activity.PredActivityLinks.ToList())
    {
        //activity.PredActivityLinks.Remove(al);
        UnitOfWork.ActivityLinkService.Delete(al);
    }

    //remove succ links
    foreach (ActivityLink al in activity.SuccActivityLinks.ToList())
    {
        //al.SuccActivity.EarliestStartDate = Project
        //activity.SuccActivityLinks.Remove(al);
        UnitOfWork.ActivityLinkService.Delete(al);
    }

    Delete(activity);
}
```

Then you have communication threads

```
internal void DeleteThread(CommunicationThread communicationThread)
{
    var threadContentTags = communicationThread.CommunicationThreadContentTags.ToList();
    foreach(var threadContentTag in threadContentTags)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationThreadContentTagService.Delete(threadContentTag);
    }
    communicationThread.CommunicationThreadContentTags.Clear();

    var threadParticipants = communicationThread.CommunicationThreadParticipants.ToList();
    foreach (var threadParticipant in threadParticipants)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationThreadParticipantService.Delete(threadParticipant);
    }
    communicationThread.CommunicationThreadParticipants.Clear();

    var threadMessages = communicationThread.CommunicationMessages.ToList();
    foreach (var threadMessage in threadMessages.Where(msg => msg.CommentOnMessageID == null))
    {
        UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationMessageService.DeleteMessage(threadMessage);
    }
    communicationThread.CommunicationMessages.Clear();

    Delete(communicationThread);
}
```

delete, we can ignore deleting threads and messages. `saveChanges()` is called when the save button is pushed

```
public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
{
    if (!CanDelete(entityToDelete)) return;
    if (EntityContext.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
    }

    DbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
}
```

Comment: The markdown formatting can be tricky. The backticks are meant to create inline code formatting. This doesn't look very well when applied to a block code of code ranging many lines. To format that properly, increase the indentation of each line by 4 spaces (or a tab). this can be quite a pain as your code is likely already indented in your code editor. What works great for me is to un-indent the block of code that you want to copy down to one level (not entirely to the left, just one tab shy of it), then copy the block to past it here, then undo the indentation in your code.

Comment: Apart from the invalid unit-of-work usage you didn't show the most important part of the code namely how you actually delete something. You call some methods but this is not enough. We need to know how they are implemented. What you have posted is an example how to use your API but the API itself remains a mystery. Maybe you create a new connection for each delete-call, maybe you don't dispose something, who knows.

Comment: @t3chb0t I hav edited the code to include the delete.

Answer (score 2):

If you have dependent entities, you can (and probably should) use [foreign key constraints](//stackoverflow.com/a/6260736/1157100) in your database to enforce referential integrity.  Define foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and the appropriate cascading deletes will happen automatically when you delete the subproject.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I would like to know how to make this better in linq and c#. Thank you for this.